# listing directories and sub-directories to an array with path;

Tags: arrays, perl, directory

I need a listing of all directories and sub-directories stored in array using Perl.

For example:

```
$array[0] = '/home';
$array[1] = '/home/ali';
$array[2] = '/home/perl';
$array[3] = '/home/stackoverflow';
$array[4] = '/home/ali/desktop';
$array[5] = '/home/ali/sub';
$array[6] = '/home/stackoverflow/new';
```

Comment: This list of directories and their subdirectories, your program ferrets it out for itself? As opposed to you feeding it the information from an input file, perhaps compiled using `ls`.

Comment: can i use `ls` to listing to arrays?

Comment: `ls`, if you're on a linux machinge will list files and subdirectories in the current working directory. If you only want subdirectories, cd to `home/` and in a bash terminal try `find home/ -type d`, and that will print you a list of all subdirectories, including `/home`. You can then either feed this into your program as an input file (simpler), or get your program to run the command, probably like calling a bash script. These commands only run on Unix systems, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
use File::Find::Rule;
my @array = File::Find::Rule->directory->in('/home');
```

[File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find::Rule)

Comment: well you need to tell us why you cannot use the way shown if we are to suggest an alternative that does not have the same unstated defect...

Answer (score 1):

```
my @array = ('/home', grep -d, glob '/home/*');
```

Comment: That won't recurse as requested, and it'll skip directories whose name starts with `.`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the old-fashioned way:

```
File::Find::find( sub {
        say $File::Find::name if -d $File::Find::name
    }, @array 
    );
```